# Arduino 1.6.1 IDE with Teensyduino Serial port lag issue?

Tags: serial, teensy

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Board: Teensy 3.1 and Arduino UNO

I've ran many tests and concluded that the issue is within the Arduino IDE itself.

The issue: Instead of a smooth stream of data displaying from the serial port, the terminal displays big chunks of data periodically.

I tested it with minicom and the stream of data is smooth.

Any solutions?

Comment: how fast is 'periodically'? I'm not surprised minicom is better, but unless the arduino terminal is really _broken_ I don't think there is anything to fix.

Comment: around once per second.